# Alternatvie to changes package

Tags: todonotes, changes, trackchanges

Currently, for comments in the text (displayed in the compiled pdf) I use the 'todonotes' package with the ability to turn it on and off in the final pdf. I also need to use the text changes functionality similar to the 'changes' package. Unfortunately, both packages do not want to work together. I can't resign from the 'todonotes' package (too many comments in tex files). Do you know any alternative? I need to highlight the text that was added/changed possibly with a comment.

> "message": "Option clash for package todonotes.

does not work:

```
\usepackage{changes}
```

with:

```
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes} % <- OFF
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes} % <- ON
% 
\newcommandx{\unsure}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red,size=\normalsize,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\change}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!25,bordercolor=blue,size=\normalsize,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\info}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=OliveGreen,backgroundcolor=OliveGreen!25,bordercolor=OliveGreen,size=\normalsize,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\improvement}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=Plum,backgroundcolor=Plum!25,bordercolor=Plum,size=\normalsize,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\thiswillnotshow}[2][1=]{\todo[disable,#1]{#2}}
```

main .tex file:

```
\documentclass{report}
%
% 

\usepackage{changes} % does not work with todonotes


%================ TO DO LIST=============================
% todonotes ON/OFF
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes} % 
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes} %


\begin{document}

x
\end{document}
%+++ END +++
```

Comment: option clash errors are easy to resolve, but you should make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: you can almost always avoid an option clash by following the advice given if you respond with `h` which will detail the exact options to adjust. But as you have provided no example it is hard to give any more specific advice.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer

I added my main .tex file

Comment: It's not really reasonable to post a 100 line example for an option clash. It does not give an option clash error anyway it gives `! LaTeX Error: File \`Rozdzial2.tex' not found.`  Please post a small complete example that gives the error you are asking about, without all the extra packages not needed to show the problem.

Comment: I edited the example this time.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I thought there were too many packages

Comment: You should make it easy for people to trace issues by minimising the example, but even in your real document do you _really_ use all those packages? Don't include packages "just in case" only include them if actually used in the document. you load several packages twice (eg graphicx, siunitx) it doesn't actually load twice but makes it harder to debug option clashes as you need to work out which one really loaded. You have conflicting font packages, you can use amsfonts or newtxmath but not both at the same time

Answer (score 2):

changes loads todonotes anyway and allows you to pass options to it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[todonotes={colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny}]{changes} 
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Beautiful prose in the example text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle blub would be better ;-)

Comment: Yes, but:
`[{
 "resource": "/c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changes/changes.sty",
 "owner": "LaTeX",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Package changes: Command comment is already defined..\n",
 "source": "LaTeX",
 "startLineNumber": 783,
 "startColumn": 1,
 "endLineNumber": 783,
 "endColumn": 65536
},{
 "resource": "/c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changes/changes.sty",
 "owner": "LaTeX",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Command \\comment already defined.\n",
 "source": "LaTeX",
 "startLineNumber": 794,
 "startColumn": 1,
 "endLineNumber": 794,
 "endColumn": 65536
}]`

Comment: changes has  documentation. I recommend the section `Command already defined`. And learn to copy error messages from the actual log-file. That makes them much more readable.

Comment: The problem was with the combination of commands, the solution:
`% \usepackage[commandnameprefix=ifneeded,todonotes={disable}]{changes} % <- TO DO notes OFF` and 
`\usepackage[commandnameprefix=ifneeded,todonotes=colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny}]{changes} <-TO DO notes ON`
one of the lines needs to be commented out
Thank you for you help